# Python date calculating with year and week of year is incorrect

Tags: python, date, week-number

We are having an issue when calculating the start of the first week in 2019.

The parameters are `year` and `week_of_year`. We are always staring the week at Monday.

The code to get the first day of a specific year:

```
from datetime import datetime

result = datetime.strptime('%04d-%02d-1' % (year, week_of_year), '%Y-%W-%w').date()
```

This works for most of the years, but not in the case when `year = 2019` and `week_of_year = 1`, Python computes this to the date `2019-01-02` and not the expected `2018-12-31`.

Our current solution to solve this problem is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

result = datetime.strptime('%04d-%02d-1' % (year, week_of_year), '%Y-%W-%w').date()

# Fixes issue with Python date computing returning the incorrect date
# This only occures for some years. E.g. 2019.
offset = result.isocalendar()[1] - datetime.strptime('%04d-01-01' % year, '%Y-%m-%d').date().isocalendar()[1]
if offset > 0:
    result = result - timedelta(days=7)
```

Any other ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What are your rules for when the first day of the first week starts in Dec? E.g. `(2016, 1)` gives `Jan 4th` and not `Dec  28th`, i.e. why is `Dec 31st` and not `Jan 7th` correct (note: I get `Jan 7th` not `Jan 2nd`).

Comment: @AChampion Hmm. When getting the week number from 2019-01-07 it says 2 and not 1. Looking at my Mac calendar it also says that the date 2018-12-31 has the week number 1 in the year 2019 :P

Comment: What version of Python are you using, I'm on 3.7 (and a Mac) and getting the week number from `2019-01-07 == 1`. `datetime(2019, 1, 7).strftime('%W') # '01'` (not surprisingly I get `53` for the week number `2018/12/31`).

Comment: BTW The Mac Calendar.app starts at `1` if you want to replicate that in Python, just use week `0`. i.e. Calendar.app shows `Week 1 for 2017 as Dec 26th - Jan 1st`. Python handles the case where Mon is Jan 1st by having week 0 and week 1 will return the same value `2018-01-01`.

Comment: @AChampion Aha. We are using Python 2.7. Testing locally on my Mac using Python 2.7.14, running `datetime(2019, 1, 7).strftime('%W')` returns 1 while running datetime(2019, 1, 7).isocalendar()[1] returns 2.

Comment: Python by default uses `0` based weeks, you are mixing python's `0` based week numbering and iso based `1` numbering. I think you just need to set your week number to `0` in your `strptime()` call. It will give you week `1` in isocalendar.

Comment: @AChampion makes sense. If you summaries this in an answer I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it is more complicated than this... `isocalendar()` is more complicated than I originally thought. It is based on a full 52 or 53 week year, so week 1 does not map simply to week 0 in python, e.g. `datetime(2016, 1, 1).isocalendar() # (2015, 53, 5)`,  and `datetime(2013, 12, 31).isocalendar() # (2014, 1, 2)`. BTW the Calendar.app is just a 1 based calendar week and is equivalent to 0-based week in Python. Do you really need `isocalendar()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After consulting https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior, I can tell that `%W` does not respect ISO-definition of the week counter, but simply counts from the first monday in a year. The days before are put into week count 0...

You can try `%V` together with `%G`:

```
result = datetime.strptime('%04d-%02d-1' % (year, 1), '%G-%V-%w').date()
```